# Upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 with wrong user name and can't access any files

Tags: permissions, username

I cannot login to the old username because it does not exist on the login screen.
I cannot recreate the old username because I don't have root privileges. 
I have tried many methods of getting to root mode and none work.
Is there any way of changing the new username to the old one?

I usually get this message:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

Comment: create a live cd or bootable usb key, start from that, mount the harddisk and fix the sudoers.so permissions

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: I only know Windows. I shall attempt to "fix the sudoers.so permissions" whatever that is!

Comment: if that is the case: re-install 14.04. It probably will be easier to save those files you want saving to a USB stick and just re-install.

Comment: I booted up on the usb again but I am still not in root mode. I can't find 'sudoers.so permissions'

Comment: I suspect that the upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 got into an endless loop after several hours. I now get a message saying "the volume Filesystem root has only 0 bytes disk space remaining."
There are 49.2 GB used 0 bytes free.
The USB drives don't work as it says they need drivers. The monitor won't work properly as it says "Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors"

Answer (score 7):

Start by rebooting into recovery mode ([covered on this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)). Get up to the point where you're root.

After that look at `stat /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`. I see:

```
...
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
...
```

By the looks of it, that won't ring true for you but not entirely sure what you've done. If the owner isn't root or the permissions are anything but 0644, we can fix that quickly:

```
chown root: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
chmod 0644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

If that permissions/ownership is the only problem, that should fix it. Just run `reboot` to boot back into Ubuntu-proper.

If you nuked /usr completely (with a `chmod -r ... /usr`, for example), you need to restore ownerships to a lot more files. Thankfully, `/usr` is *fairly* rooty. You can restore the bulk of permissions with:

```
chown -r root /usr
chown daemon /usr/bin/at
chown libuuid /usr/sbin/uuidd
```

If you want to know how I got those two stragglers, I ran `sudo find /usr -exec stat -c '%U %n' {} + | grep -v root` on a cleanish system. If you have a recent backup, I'd suggest running that against your backup.

Comment: It's very difficult to do anything because it won't allow me to set the screen resolution correctly, so I can only see a quarter of the screen.

Comment: Oh man, when it rains it pours! Right you could do this via a Live CD/USB (assuming you have one); just follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot) up to and including step 11. That should make you root on your install system which should put you in a position to fix things.

Comment: @Oli I did the silly thing and ran `sudo chown $USER -r /usr`. Can you please explain what should be done?

Comment: @Tushar Well that *was* silly. I've added an edit that should restore most of `/usr` to its rightful ownerships. You'll still need to start by rebooting into recovery mode though.

Comment: So, me or my hubbie must have done a similar silly thing on his Ubuntu machine as Tushar. Will probably want to do a reinstall, but need to backup some stuff first - but, I can't connect to internet or connect USB. Does anybody know what the ownership should be for `/media` or other things that affect how the USB works? The answer above doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: `/usr/bin/at` no such file..

Comment: @gsamaras If you don't have it, there's nothing to restore. Carry on.

Comment: OK, well I do not know if I have double-nuked my pc, but now when in recovery mode, on root, I give my password and on enter, the screen flashes and I am prompt to the menu resume, clean, dpkg, etc..any idea? You see I was double silly and I did `sudo chown $USER -r /`