# Not able to access Internet after running sudo chown -R $USER$USER /usr/lib/

Tags: command-line, networking, permissions, chown

I wanted to update PyCharm, and when running Pycharm it was not possible since it said that I did not have enough permissions. So I run the following command:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER$USER /usr/lib/
```

I was able to update PyCharm successfully, but now my Internet connection is not working, and actually I was not able to run sudo after I access the recovery mode following [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499465/upgraded-from-13-10-to-14-04-with-wrong-user-name-and-cant-access-any-files).

I really need my Internet connection working again, so please I would appreciate your help to solve this issue.

I have to mention that I am using a dual boot.

Comment: chmod/chown is like vodka. At first it seems to solve all your problems, but later you just get a bigger headache. Don't use them (especially with -R!) unless you are 100% confident you know what you are doing. Were you able to access recovery mode successfully? Your question leaves that a bit unclear.

Comment: your installation is screwed. like they say "chown fixes your problem, but one day it gives you a headache." you will have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: I have a repository that I need to push, how can I force to connect to the Internet, push the code and the restart the system?

Comment: use a livecd ^^^

Comment: If you didn't have enough permissions to update PyCharm but you were able to run `sudo`, why didn't you update PyCharm as root in the first place?

Comment: This situation can be fixed pretty easily. Please consider repairs before contemplating reinstallation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any sort of `chown` operation on system directories is ***very dangerous***.

The easiest way to solve this problem would to be just to reinstall your operating system entirely.

If you're lucky (and a bit of a risk-taker), you might be able to recover by simply running the below command from recovery mode:

```
chown -R root:root /usr/lib
```

While *most* files are owned by root in `/usr/lib`, there might still be the occasional file that *isn't* which will cause major problems if it's not actively owned by the appropriate user. In fact, on your (average) Linux installation, most files in this directory are owned by `root`/`root`, so this is definitely worth a shot if reinstallation is undesirable.

Otherwise, you'd have to go through each file and manually re-assign permissions to their normal values (typically meaning owned by `root`, but not in all cases). On occasion, you can just re-install all packages (using `apt --reinstall install <packagename>`), but this is not guaranteed, and may still cause more headaches than it solves. Really, you'd be going through each file and running `dpkg -L` on them.

As for preserving your files in your current system (if you go down the reinstall your OS path), you can use a flash drive in recovery mode. If you need to upload some files to Git at the last second, you can probably use a Live DVD (pulling SSH keys and anything important from your wrecked install).

---

In the future, to prevent this exact type of problem from happening again, make sure you have a (working -- check it!) backup of your system and any important files.

Also, it's important to note that `sudo` is ***not*** a one-shot-fix-all solution for any permission error, and should not be used that way! If there's a permission error, there's probably a very good reason you don't have permissions to do that thing, so investigate and solve it in a sane manner.

Comment: Good point. Not everything is necessarily owned by root. Recovery at this point is likely impossible.

Comment: what about backups?!?

Comment: @KazWolfe, I have a repository, and I need to push the code I have there. Is there any way to force a connection before reinstalling the OS?

Comment: @Edity good point, editing in now.

Comment: backups are really important peoples, one day your pc might have not enough blood and backups are like from a blood doner

Comment: all im saying is, backups are important. your pc's life might depend on one

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf From your OS as is? No. You can, however, use a live environment, pulling your SSH keys and any important files from your `/home` on your bad install.

Comment: @imiguelvargasf like seth said, recovery at this point is likely impossible. unless you have enthernet. wait try that

Comment: @Edity, thank you. I tried ethernet. I was able to connect to the Internet, and push my code. But I will need to reinstall the OS.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf no need to reinstall...

Answer (score 14):

Actually, no need to reinstall. This situation is quite reparable. I just ran the same command on my system and fixed it in about 10 minutes.

You will need to either boot in recovery mode, or use a live USB/DVD of any Linux version (preferably Ubuntu!)

If you prefer recovery, please see [How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode#150377)

I used a live USB with Xubuntu 16.04 that I had to hand. If using a live session, after booting, open a terminal and identify your root (main) partition, using commands such as `lsblk` and `sudo fdisk -l`. When you know which one it is (it will likely be an `ext4` partition), mount it. Here I am calling the root partition `/dev/sda1` - you need to replace this with the real label.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

now check it is the right partition by doing `ls /mnt` - you should see `usr  sys  proc  dev  home  root` and other things you would expect to find at the top of the filesystem tree. OK, let's fix the ownership (in all these commands, please take careful note of the `:` and be sure to put these in the right places).

```
sudo chown -R root: /mnt/usr/lib
```

That almost fixes it. On my system, before I broke it, I checked out all the ownerships on that location

```
$ find /usr/lib -not -user root
```

returns nothing - root owns everything, but

```
$ find /usr/lib -not -group root -ls
```

Turned up this:

```
-rwxr-sr-x   1 root     mail          /usr/lib/emacs/24.5/x86_64-linux-gnu/movemail
-rwxr-sr-x   1 root     tty           /usr/lib/mc/cons.saver
-rwsr-xr--   1 root     messagebus    /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
-rwxr-sr-x   1 root     utmp          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/utempter/utempter
```

Your system will not be exactly the same, but you should `chown` those files if you have them, and look for equivalents if not (for example if you system is 32-bit, you would have `x86` instead of `x86_64`). I fixed these with:

```
sudo chown :mail /mnt/usr/lib/emacs/24.5/x86_64-linux-gnu/movemail
sudo chown :tty /mnt/usr/lib/mc/cons.saver
sudo chown :messagebus /mnt/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
sudo chown :utmp /mnt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/utempter/utempter
```

(if using recovery mode, you will not need `/mnt` at the start of those paths)

As [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863249/not-able-to-access-internet-after-running-sudo-chown-r-useruser-usr-lib/863270?noredirect=1#comment1332931_863270) by @grawity, you also need to repair the `setuid` bit on `dbus-daemon-launch-helper` which is cleared by `chown`:

```
sudo chmod u+s /mnt/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

Comment: Most importantly, dbus-daemon-launch-helper needs its setuid bit reapplied as well (`chmod u+s` after chowning). You can find those using `find -perm /7000`.

Comment: I think you forgot the `/mnt` on the `utempter` path (2nd to last code block, last line)

Comment: @fkraiem we did some polling in chat and we all found that everything belongs to root with these or very similar files with different group ownership (a mod suggested I post an answer). I believe this repair strategy would well work for most users, and would likely be preferable to reinstalling. I haven't suggested anything destructive here.

Comment: @fkraiem it's still a valid answer. It's not only for OP. If it works for OP, that's great; they got what they needed. If it doesn't, it still might work for someone else who visits this page. Besides, at this point, with the only other option being a reinstall, what's the harm in trying?

Comment: @fkraiem you're wrong. it can still work for other people, so why harm the answer if it's valid?